# Status of OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I've been looking at switching over to an object database and stumbled upon OrientDB.  I really like what I'm seeing, particularly the Java Object API.  It's been around for awhile and their website looks new and shiny, but the community forums on the site appear to be dead and the documentation seems out-of-date. I've asked several questions there and have received no answers or views.  Have I discovered this product too late? Should I look for something else?  Anyone have any insight into the state of this product?

Answer (score 1):

Not dead at all, OrientDB is still being actively developed and all docs are updated to the latest version which is [3.0](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/), but you can also find the [3.1 beta](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.1.x/) and previous versions such as [2.1](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/) and [2.2](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/).